# Prove a set is closed in the standard topology of the Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $B$ be a closed and bounded  set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $h>0$. Prove that $$ \bigcup_{y\in[0,\,h]} (1-\frac{y}{h})B\times\{y\} $$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I have a proof that is extremely technical but somehow I feel like there should be a nice elegant trick for this. It is true that as the union is infinite, even though each unionand (from summand) is closed, the union is not necessarily closed. But is there still a way to salvage this?

Comment: **Hint** Since the topology is $N2$, a set is closed if and only if it is sequentially closed...

Comment: Sequential closedness is what is used in the technical proof. How do you use it here elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. In $\mathbb {R}^1,$ let $B = [0,\infty).$ Take $h=1.$ Then $(1-y)B = B$ for all $y\in [0,1),$ but $= \{0\}$ when $y=1.$ Thus the union in question equals $([0,\infty)\times [0,1)) \cup \{(0,1)\},$ which is not closed in $\mathbb {R}^2.$

Added later: If $B$ is assumed to be compact, then we can define $f:B\times [0,h] \to \mathbb {R}^{n+1}$ as follows: $f(x,y) = ((1-y/h)x,y).$ Then $f(B\times [0,h])$ is exactly the set of interest. Clearly $f$ is continuous. Since $B\times [0,h]$ is compact, so is $f(B\times [0,h]).$

Comment: I apologize I forgot to mention B is bounded.

Comment: Note the "added later" in my answer above.